# Compare each row's column to a particular row's column

Tags: sql

I have two tables: one table (okay, it's a view), vComputer, lists many computers by unique GUID.  Another table, Inv_Screensaver_File_Info, lists a computer if it has run a custom inventory and reported how current its screensaver files are.

I need to list the GUIDs of all computers who are not present in Inv_Screensaver_File_Info, and also any computers who are present but whose Inv_Screensaver_File_Info.LastModified value is less than a particular record's result in that table, which represents the authoritative source.

This is the record I want all rows to compare to:
MYSERVER    B5A85423-26C4-40C0-DA28-237FB4CB0B33        2012-02-09 11:38:50.000
The unique GUID exists as vc.Guid and also as sfi._ResourceGuid

What is the SQL method for doing this?

```
SELECT vc.Name,
vc.Guid,
sfi.LastModified
FROM vComputer vc
LEFT OUTER JOIN Inv_Screensaver_File_Info sfi ON sfi._ResourceGuid=vc.Guid
WHERE sfi.LastModified IS NULL
ORDER BY sfi.LastModified DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT vc.Name, vc.Guid
FROM vComputer vc
     LEFT JOIN Inv_Screensaver_File_Info sfi ON sfi._ResourceGuid=vc.Guid
     INNER JOIN vComputer vc2 ON vc2.Guid = 'B5A85423-26C4-40C0-DA28-237FB4CB0B3'
     INNER JOIN Inv_Screensaver_File_Info sfi2 ON sfi2._ResourceGuid = vc2.Guid
WHERE sfi.LastModified IS NULL
   OR sfi.LastModified < sfi2.LastModified
```

Comment: Unfortunately, LastModified does not exist in vComputer. I've tried heavily modifying your suggestion but I couldn't get it to work. Does the authoritative source's (Guid 'B5A85423-26C4-40C0-DA28-237FB4CB0B33' in vc. and .sfi) data need to be in a separate table?

Comment: @mikeclemson what value, do you care about when you are comparing to  MYSERVER B5A85423-26C4-40C0-DA28-237FB4CB0B33 2012-02-09 11:38:50.000

Comment: @mikeclemson check it out now

Comment: Good question.  I want to list all computers in vComputer whose Inv_Screensaver_File_Info.LastModified value is less than the Inv_Screensaver_File_Info.LastModified value of MYSERVER.  MYSERVER can be identified in Inv_Screensaver_File_Info by it's GUID.  In addition to those whose value is less than MYSERVER's, I also need any records that do not exist in Inv_Screensaver_File_Info but do exist in vComputer vc.

Comment: @mikeclemson I changed it again just now, because if I understand correctly, you have a table called MyServer or something, if MyServer is just an entry in vComputer, you'll have to switch it back

Comment: This was the correct query:
SELECT
vc.Guid
FROM vComputer vc      
LEFT JOIN Inv_Screensaver_File_Info sfi ON sfi._ResourceGuid=vc.Guid      
INNER JOIN vComputer vc2 ON vc2.Guid = 'A5A85423-26F4-40C0-AB28-237FB4CB0B33'      
INNER JOIN Inv_Screensaver_File_Info sfi2 ON sfi2._ResourceGuid=vc2.Guid 
WHERE 
(sfi.LastModified IS NULL OR sfi.LastModified < (sfi2.LastModified))

Answer (score 0):

It's always a bit hard to answer query-questions without a schema and an example of the desired output, but here's an attempt.

```
select vc.Name, vc.Guid, vc.LastModified
from   vComputer vc
where  not exists(select 1
                  from   Inv_Screensaver_File_Info sfi
                  where  sfi._ResourceGuid = vc.Guid)
or     exists(select 1
              from   Inv_Screensaver_File_Info sfi1
                     inner join Inv_Screensaver_File_Info sfi2
                         on sfi2.ResourceGuid = sfi1.ResourceGuid and
                            sfi2.LastModified < sfi1.LastModified
              where  sfi._ResourceGuid = vc.Guid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you need the just the guid, add vc.Name to the select and group by if you need that too:

```
DECLARE @CutoffDateTime UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SELECT @CutoffDateTime = LastModified FROM MyServer WHERE Guid = 'B5A85423-26C4-40C0-DA28-237FB4CB0B33'
SELECT vc.Guid
FROM vComputer vc
LEFT OUTER JOIN Inv_Screensaver_File_Info sfi ON sfi._ResourceGuid = vc.Guid
GROUP BY vc.Guid
HAVING MAX(sfi.LastModified) < @CutoffDate || MAX(sfi.LastModified) IS NULL
```